Non recursive convert python object graph to dictionary
I found this function through this thread regarding converting python object graph to dictionary
def todict(obj, classkey=None):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        data = {}
        for (k, v) in obj.items():
            data[k] = todict(v, classkey)
        return data
    elif hasattr(obj, "_ast"):
        return todict(obj._ast())
    elif hasattr(obj, "__iter__") and not isinstance(obj, str):
        return [todict(v, classkey) for v in obj]
    elif hasattr(obj, "__dict__"):
        data = dict([(key, todict(value, classkey)) 
            for key, value in obj.__dict__.items() 
            if not callable(value) and not key.startswith('_')])
        if classkey is not None and hasattr(obj, "__class__"):
            data[classkey] = obj.__class__.__name__
        return data
    else:
        return obj

However, this is breaching the maximum recursion limit for my project. Can somebody help to see if there's a way to use stack to rewrite this function into a non-recursive approach?
Thanks.
currently this is what I have but it's not returning the full result data as the recursive function does.
def to_dict(obj, classkey=None):
    stack = [(obj, classkey)]
    result = {}

    while stack:
        current_obj, key = stack.pop()

        # Check if current_obj is a dictionary
        if isinstance(current_obj, dict):
            data = {}
            for k, v in current_obj.items():
                stack.append((v, k))

        # Check if current_obj has _ast attribute
        elif hasattr(current_obj, "_ast"):
            stack.append((current_obj._ast()))

        # Check if current_obj is iterable (excluding strings)
        elif hasattr(current_obj, "__iter__") and not isinstance(current_obj, str):
            arr = [v for v in current_obj]
            for v in arr:
                stack.append((v, key))

        # Check if current_obj has __dict__ attribute
        elif hasattr(current_obj, "__dict__"):
            data = {}
            for k, v in current_obj.__dict__.items():
                if not callable(v) and not k.startswith("_"):
                    stack.append((v, k))
            if key is not None and hasattr(current_obj, "__class__"):
                data[key] = current_obj.__class__.__name__

        # Otherwise, it's a leaf node
        else:
            data = current_obj

        # If there's a key, update result accordingly
        if key is not None:
            if isinstance(result, list):
                result[key] = data
            elif isinstance(result, dict):
                result[key] = data
        else:
            result = data

    return result


Are you sure you don't have loops in your data? The default recursion limit is 1000, which should be far more than enough for any reasonable set of nested objects.

Yes we dont, it's just a very complex input that is nested more than 10k times.

If you know you need that much recursion, just increase the recursion limit.

It's not sustainable and I think once the recursion limit hits 10 15k Python breaks so trying to find a nonrecursive way here
